# Ldap Authentication with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am rails developer and i am trying to implement the ldap authentication with devise,But i am not able to open the ldap port as it giving me the following error:
Deprecation warning: Net::LDAP::ConnectionRefused will be deprecated. Use Errno::ECONNREFUSED instead.

I am really thankful if anyone can help me out,I am searching about it for a long time.

Comment: follow this video hope it helps http://corrupt.net/2010/07/05/LDAP-Authentication-With-Devise/

Comment: There's a gem for LDAP authentication with devise 
https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable plus it's documentation is also dead simple.

Comment: I have done with using this gem and follow all the steps from the github but its still not working

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari i have tried to implement from the video but at the time of starting server i am geting this error on mac :

 /usr/libexec/slapd -d 1 
slap_open_listener: failed on ldap:///